# Swift Spritekit NSUserdefaults between 2 swift scenes/files

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do i share NSUserdefaults objects between 2 scenes/files

so if i create 1 in hello.swift

i will be able to load it in dad.swift?

i tried to do it the normal way but it didn't seem to work

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: What do you use for the "normal way"? Also, what do you mean by "it didn't seem to work"? Did you get a crash, error, or did it not save properly?

Comment: did not save properly? do i have to add something like NSuserDefaults.save after i set a object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is shared throughout the application. If you put this in one file:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myObject, forKey: "key")
```

Then you can retrieve it in another file:

```
var myObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key")
```

Comment: I would create a specific file to hold this data and any extensions you use just so it's not as messy and easier to navigate

Answer (score -1):

Example;

Add prefs with that codes.

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

When you add object use this.

```
 let test = "test"
 prefs.setObject(test, forKey: "test")
```

For using object from prefs

```
 print("\(prefs.valueForKey("test") as! String!)")
```

> After you can easily add more more objects with using prefs

Such as  `prefs.setObject(test2, forKey: "test2")`

Thanks

Comment: The same answer has already been posted. Also, you do not need to import System Configuration

Comment: @penatheboss i answered true way with object and usage.

Comment: @penatheboss no you can use NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() everytime more more but i can use only prefs. less codes and true way

Comment: That makes no difference, especially if you are using it in 2 different files. There is no "true way" as the problem could be approached through several different contexts